# Javascript - enabling button when input is filled

Tags: javascript, html

I want to enable my button, when input is filled. I want to do it in pure Javascript.

My code example in HTML:

```
<form action="sent.php" method="post" name="frm">
  <input type="text" name="name_input" id="name" onkeyup="myFunction()"><br>
  <button type="submit" class="button button-dark" id="send">Send message</button>
</form>
```

And Javascript:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    document.getElementById('send').disabled = "true";
    function myFunction() {
        var nameInput = document.getElementById('name').value;
        if (!nameInput === "") {
            document.getElementById('send').disabled = "false";
        } 
    }
});
```

I don't know why my button is not changing to enable state after filling something in input. I have tried diffrent ways to do it, but it's still not working.
Please help.

Comment: Have you checked the browers console for errors?

Comment: Don’t mix different approaches to event handling like this (addEventListener vs onkeyup attribute.) Most likely, you should see an error message in console saying that there is no function `myFunction` - because of how you nested that function into the DOMContentLoaded event, but reference it in the HTML code directly. Use addEventListener  to bind the keyup event listener as well - from inside the DOMContentLoaded handler.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem with your code is that `myFunction()` isn't available because you defined it in the eventlistener for click.

Complete refactored code answer:

HTML

```
<form action="sent.php" method="post" name="frm">
    <input type="text" name="name_input" id="name">
    <br>
    <button type="submit" class="button button-dark" id="send" disabled>Send message</button>
</form>
```

JS

```
document.getElementById("name").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
    var nameInput = document.getElementById('name').value;
    if (nameInput != "") {
        document.getElementById('send').removeAttribute("disabled");
    } else {
        document.getElementById('send').setAttribute("disabled", null);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 7):

An input element in HTML is enabled only when the `disabled` attribute is **not present**.

In your case `disabled` is always present in your element, it's just that it has a "false" or a "true" value - but this is meaningless according to the specs (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp)

So you need to remove it altogether:

```
 document.getElementById('send').removeAttribute('disabled')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one it will work for you

```
 function myFunction() {
            document.getElementById('send').disabled = true;
            var nameInput = document.getElementById('name').value;
            if (nameInput != "") {
            alert("Empty");
                document.getElementById('send').disabled = false;
            }
    }
```

if you want to check the input should not be contain number then we can use isNaN() function, it will return true if number is not number otherwise return false

Comment: OP doesn't use jQuery. Mixing jQuery and vanilla-js isn't good practics btw.

Comment: ok then remove the   $( document ).ready(function() {
                myFunction();
}); part

Comment: also add disabled attribute to ur button so that initially button not clickable

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost correct but you have defined `myFunction` inside a block, so `input` is not able to find `myFunction()` inside `onkeyup="myFunction()"`

so just keep the same outside of `DOMContentLoaded` event

see working **[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sanjaynishad/v3mcqomr/)**

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    document.getElementById('send').disabled = "true";
});
function myFunction() {
    var nameInput = document.getElementById('name').value;
    console.log(nameInput);
    if (nameInput === "") {
        document.getElementById('send').disabled = true;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('send').disabled = false;
    }
}
```